# Updating parent of recursive component in Vue

Tags: recursion, vue.js

I've made a menu showing systems and their subsystems (can in theory be indefinitely) using a recursive component. A user can both add and delete systems, and the menu should therefore update accordingly.

[image: Recursive menu]

The menu is constructed using a "tree"-object. This tree is therefore updated when a new system is added, or one deleted. But, I now have a problem; even though the new child component is added when the tree is rerendered, the classes of it's parent-component doesn't update. It is necessary to update this because it defines the menu-element to having children/subsystems, and therefore showing them.

[image: Tree-object]

Therefore, when adding a new subsystem, this is presented to the user:

```
<div class="">
  <a href="#/Admin/364" class="item">
    <i class=""></i>Testname
    <div class=""></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Instead of this:

```
<div class="menu transition visible" style="display: block !important;">
  <a href="#/Admin/364" class="item">
    <i class=""></i>Testname
    <div class=""></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

It works fine adding a subsystem to a system which already have subsystems (since the menu-class is already present), but not when a subsystem is added to one without subsystems. In that case, the menu ends up looking like this:
[image: Menu when new subsystem is added]

The "opposite" problem also occurs on deletion, since the parent still has the menu-class:
[image: On deletion]

Here's the code for the recursive component:

```
<template>
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Admin', params: { systemId: id } }" class="item" >
  <i :class="{ dropdown: hasChildren, icon: hasChildren }"></i>{{name}}
    <div :class="{ menu: hasChildren }">
      <systems-menu-sub-menu v-for="child in children" :children="child.children" :name="child.name" :id="child.id" :key="child.id"/>
    </div>
</router-link>
</template>

<script type = "text/javascript" >

export default {
  props: ['name', 'children', 'id'],
  name: 'SystemsMenuSubMenu',
  data () {
    return {
      hasChildren: (this.children.length > 0)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm guessing this has to do with Vue trying to be efficient, and therefore not rerendering everything. Is there therefore any way to force a rerender, or is there any other workaround?

**EDIT:** JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f6s5qzba/

Comment: It might be a bad idea to use `id` as a prop since it might conflict with the `id` HTML attribute for `:id="child.id"`. Providing a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) would be a big help.

Comment: this seems like an interesting problem. It would be nice to provide the full or portion of the code to work on

Comment: I've now added a JSFiddle, see edit in original post.